# Setting up Security Realm in Weblogic 10.3

Tags: weblogic

how can i setup security realm in weblogic 10.3? i wan't to add user roles and let weblogic server to check those users for what resources they can access. Where weblogic stores authentication data? how can authentication data can be accessed and updated by weblogic server automatically?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague since there are a lot of ways to configure security within Weblogic. Oracle's [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/secmanage/realm.html#wp1188256) would be a good starting point.

You can setup the security realm under Security Realms in the console. There are some default groups with specific roles that you could assign to user accounts (for example, monitor = readonly).

LDAP data is stored in the internal LDAP folder within the domain directory. However, you can configure it to use an external LDAP.